# Re-iterating a for loop in a dict

Tags: python-3.x

the getid() method gives a nonetype error every time the server bans my ip(for 60s). i wish to reiterate the loop instance every time i get an error so as to not miss an item. how do i accomplish this ?

```
for t in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"vItem Normal"}):
        try:
            if(t["data-exterior"]=="Not Available"):
                continue
            name.append(t["data-hashname"])
            id_parse=requests.get(f"http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/{name[-1]}")
            item_id=getid(id_parse.text)
            skin_ids[name[-1]]=item_id
            sleep(3)
        except:
            sleep(60)
            #i want to reiterate now
```

Comment: I guess you want a `try: ... catch:` over the whole `for` loop, rather than **inside** the loop as you show above...

Comment: im pretty sure , the try catch is in the right place. if i place it outside it will end up running forever before it could go through the whole loop.

Comment: Sorry my mistake.